# Automatically select save option in webbrowser file download dialog box

Tags: browser

I have a c# desktop app which connects to a site via a web browser control. The problem is I need to navigate to a specific section and download a excel file which is generated from a postback. I would like to either automate this process or bypass the file download dialog and save the file directly to a local drive.
Problem
The link is not a standard url. The site uses a postback script to get the file needed which then displays the file download dialog box. E.g. When you click on the button (javascript: postback) the file download dialog box is automatically loaded.

As stated  I want to bypass the save options and automatically store the file in a predefined location. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I find AutoIt http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ very useful for these kind of tasks. If you want to integrate it with your C# app, then you can call your AutoIt script via system calls. The difficulty is finding and following the link on the page, that will depend on how the page is laid out.